# PhpStorm replacing template names with ellipses - how to turn it off?

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

Small question, been scouring the settings and [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html), but cannot find the option to turn off the concatenation of a template name (e.g. `admin/dashboard/dashboard.html.twig`) to ellipsis (`...`).

[image: ellipsified]

Would very much like the default setting to be the result of clicking on the ellipsis, like shown below:

[image: should be this]

I've not managed to find which setting causes this. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm personally not aware of such functionality that would collapse string function parameters... 1) What's your IDE version? 2) Please disable all 3rd party plugins (not bundled ones) and try again. Maybe it's a new functionality (e,g, if you are using 2020.1 EAP).. or provided by custom plugin.

Comment: @LazyOne Using 2019.3.2 (latest stable I think). But damn, "3rd party plugins" got me thinking. Found the issue: Symfony plugin. I'll do a quick write up as an answer. Explains why I couldn't find it in the docs though, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LazyOne's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055411/phpstorm-replacing-template-names-with-ellipses-how-to-turn-it-off#comment106212491_60055411) got me thinking it might be a third party plugin. It was:

When using Symfony's plugin, there's a few code folding settings in the plugin settings' menu, disabling those, disables the code folding issue from the question. As shown below:

[image: solution]